# Transfer variable to another view - Devextreme

Tags: devextreme

I declare a global variable in my `config.js` file :

```
var  _StockClass = 0;
```

Then I set its value from a view like this :

```
function GetListItem(e) {
    // alert('Click for Id=' + itemData.Id.toString() + ', Name=' + itemData.Name);
    _StockClass = e.StockClassID.toString();

}
```

And the View code :

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'ProductClass', title: 'Products', pane: 'master' } " >
  <div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >             
    <div data-bind="dxTextBox: { onValueChanged: onSearchTextChanged, mode: 'search' }"></div>
    <div data-bind="dxList: { dataSource: dataSource, pullRefreshEnabled: true, itemClickAction: GetListItem }">
      <div data-bind="dxAction: '#StockTypeViews/{StockClassID}'" data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } " >
        <!--
           <img height="55" style="padding: 10px; float:left;" data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrlPropertyName }" />
        -->
        <div class="list-item" data-bind="text: 'Code:' + ' ' + Code()"></div>
        <div class="list-item" data-bind="text: 'Description:' + ' ' + Description()"></div>
        <div class="list-item" data-bind="text: 'StockClassID:' + ' ' + StockClassID()" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
      </div>                  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, on the view I want to use it on I say :

```
dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: Prosound.db.StockTypeViews,
    map: function(item) {
        return new Prosound.StockTypeViewViewModel(item);
    },
    filter: [['StockClassID', '=', _StockClass], 'and', ['Active', '=', true]]
    //  searchExpr: 'StockID' //change field here for search
});
```

I have debugged and it keeps `saying _StockClass` is `0`.

How do I set its value in a view, and transfer it to another view?

Comment: I've made a sample project which uses a global variable. You could see it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9smhgxkyhhcbrq/stackoverflow-sample.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Keep your datasource code in onDeviceReady Event which will wait for your view to load.
and to pass the variable to another view ... declare your variable as global in app.config.js.